# How to get two finger tap correctly working on 14.04 with Dell 7537?

Tags: xorg, dell, touchpad, synaptics

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my Dell Inspiron 7537. The two finger tap in the touchpad that simulates the right click is not very responsive.
Sometimes it works at the first time, and sometimes I have to tap many times changing the pressure, the distance between fingers, and the speed for it to work. 
I don't know what parameter(s) to change for it to be responsive every time I tap with two fingers. In Windows it works like a charm.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you go to a terminal [Ctrl][Alt][T] and post the output of: `synclient -l` into your question?  Use [edit] first!  ;-)

Comment: Done, @Fabby. I added the output.

Comment: :-) Looks cool, but next time use text: not as cool-looking but I can copy-paste that and put it side-by-side to my output.

Comment: As I cannot look at you while you tap, we'll have to *try* some settings. (No! Don't make a video)
If you go through the list, are there any features you don't use?  E.g. if you don't use 2-finger scroll, you can just turn that off (so that it doesn't interfere with the two-finger tap)
That would be: `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0` and `synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0`

Comment: that being said: `MaxDoubleTapTime` is the easiest to change: make that 20 higher then it is now (`synclient MaxDoubleTapTime 200`) and if that isn't enough another +20
Also your hysteresis is a bit high, try setting that to 20. Try those already and then report back.
**Warning** this is not a permanent solution.  When you log off you will have lost all your settings (which is an advantage: if you |@#¼ up: just log off and back on again) the final answer will be permanent settings

Comment: I use a lot 2-finger scroll, so I leaved that untouched. I varied the parameters of MaxDoubleTapTime, VertHysteresis and HorizHysteresis, as you told me, but I didn't notice any difference. I was thinking that maybe it has to do with the time that goes by from the moment that the first finger touches the touchpad, till the other does it (i.e. the two fingers don't touch the touchpad at exactly the same time, there's a very tiny time lapse). Would that have any relevance?

Comment: Have you tried lowering MaxDoubleTapTime bringing it lower then MaxTaptime?

Comment: I tried, but I don't notice any difference either.

Comment: I'm sorry...  I'm out of ideas.  **Maybe someone with xorg knowledge can help you...** (I've added the tag for you)